# Find subarray with given sum

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

I am trying to implement functional style of finding subarray with given sum.
Code i wrote is not up to functional style. Can someone help to make it more functional.

**Problem :** Given an unsorted array of nonnegative integers, find a continous subarray which adds to a given number.

Input: arr[] = {1, 4, 20, 3, 10, 5}, sum = 33
Ouptut: Sum found between indexes 2 and 4

Input: arr[] = {1, 4, 0, 0, 3, 10, 5}, sum = 7
Ouptut: Sum found between indexes 1 and 4

I could solve this problem in brute force approach. But looking for more effective functional solution.

```
val sumList = list.foldLeft(List(0), 0)((l, r) => (l._1 :+ (l._2+r), l._2 + r))._1.drop(1)
  //Brute force approach
  sumList.zipWithIndex.combinations(2).toList.collectFirst({
    case i if i(1)._1 - i(0)._1 == sum => i
  }) match {
    case Some(List(x, y)) => println("elements which form the given sum are => "+ list.drop(x._2+1).take(y._2-x._2))
    case _ => println("couldn't find elements which satisfy the given condition")
  }
```

**Algorithm :** *Initialize a variable curr_sum as first element. curr_sum indicates the sum of current subarray. Start from the second element and add all elements one by one to the curr_sum. If curr_sum becomes equal to sum, then print the solution. If curr_sum exceeds the sum, then remove trailing elemnents while curr_sum is greater than sum.*

```
 val list:List[Int] = List(1, 4, 20, 3, 10, 5)
  val sum = 33
    
  val (totalSum, start, end, isSumFound) = list.zipWithIndex.drop(1).foldLeft(list.head, 0, 1, false)((l, r) =>
    if(!l._4) {
      val tempSum = l._1 + r._1
      if (tempSum == sum){
        (sum, l._2, r._2, true)
      } else if(tempSum > sum){
          var (curSum, curIndex) = (tempSum, l._2)
          while(curSum > sum && curIndex < list.length-1){
            curSum = curSum - list(curIndex)
            curIndex = l._2 +1
          }
        (curSum, curIndex, r._2, curSum == sum)
      } else {
        (tempSum, l._2, r._2, false)
      }
    }else
      l
  )

  if(isSumFound || totalSum == sum){
    println("elements which form the given sum are => "+ list.drop(start+1).take(end-start))
  }else{
    println("couldn't find elements which satisfy the given condition")
  }
```

Comment: Your `sumList` is more neatly expressed as `val sumList = list.scanLeft(0){_ + _}`

Comment: Hmm. and append `.drop(1)`. But it's a bit more convenient to leave the zero on the front (because then you always test the sum of list(n)-list(m) for n > m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val list:List[Int] = List(1, 4, 20, 3, 10, 5)
val sum = 33
```

A method to return a iterator of sublists, first with the ones that start with the first element, then starting with the second...

```
def subLists[T](xs:List[T]):Iterator[List[T]] =
     if (xs == Nil) Iterator.empty
     else xs.inits ++ subLists(xs.tail)
```

Find the first list with the correct sum

```
val ol = subLists(list).collectFirst{ case x if x.sum == sum => x}
```

Then find the index again, and print the result

```
ol match {
    case None => println("No such subsequence")
    case Some(l) => val i = list.indexOfSlice(l)
                println("Sequence of sum " + sum +
                        " found between " + i +
                         " and " + (i + l.length - 1))
} 
//> Sequence of sum 33 found between 2 and 4
```

(you could keep track of the index associated with the sublist when building the iterator, but that seems more trouble than it is worth, and reduces the general usefulness of `subLists`)

EDIT: Here's a version of the code you posted that's more "functional".  But I think my first version is clearer - it's simpler to separate the concerns of generating the sequences from checking their sums

```
 val sumList = list.scanLeft(0){_ + _}
 val is = for {i <- 1 to list.length - 1
                j <- 0 to i
                if sumList(i)-sumList(j) == sum}
             yield (j, i-1)

 is match {
    case Seq() => println("No such subsequence")
    case (start, end) +: _ =>
                 println("Sequence of sum " + sum +
                         " found between " + start + " and " + end )
 } 
 //> Sequence of sum 33 found between 2 and 4
```

EDIT2: And here's an O(N) one. "Functional" in that there are no mutable variables, but it's less clear than the others, in my opinion. It's a bit clearer if you just print the results as they are found (no need to carry the `rs` part of the accumulator between iterations) but that side-effecting way seems less functional, so I return a list of solutions.

```
 val sums = list.scanLeft(0)(_ + _) zipWithIndex
 sums.drop(1).foldLeft((sums, List[(Int, Int)]())) {
    case ((leftTotal, rs), total) =>
      val newL = leftTotal.dropWhile(total._1 - _._1 > target)
      if (total._1 - newL.head._1 == target)
        (newL, (newL.head._2, total._2 - 1) :: rs)
      else (newL, rs)
  }._2
  //> res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,4))
```

O(N) because we pass the shortened newL as the next iterations leftTotal, so dropWhile only ever goes through the list once.  This one relies on the integers being non-negative (so adding another element cannot reduce the total), the others work with negative integers too.

Comment: i was able to solve in brute force appraoch. am looking how can i convert while into functional style on this algo. my bruteforce approach : https://ideone.com/IID8C3

Comment: My answer is a functional approach. What do you mean by "convert while into functional style"?

Comment: i agree with you that solution given by u is perfect functional and right one. But its time complexity is O(n2). i am not so good in FP. Is it not possible to do in O(n) as the suggested algorithm in question ?

Comment: Yes, you can. I'd missed that the integers are non negative, so moving ahead can never reduce the current sum